# Android Eliminate Complete Action Using dialog

Tags: android, action, manifest

I have 2 apps and both integrate a package containing an activity. My problem is that when I launch any one app, and when it calls the activity inside the package, it shows me a dialog:

> Complete action using:
>
> App1
>
> App2

I want to eliminate this dialog, so it just launches the activity from its own integrated package.

Currently, my `AndroidManifest.xml` contains for the package activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.test.TestActivity" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Are you using an explicit intent to invoke the class?

Comment: Yes. To call the Activity inside the package, I do:
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.test.TestActivity");
startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the `<intent-filter>` for one of those two copies of the activity. Right now, both are advertising that they support the same action string. Change one to use a different action string. Or, don't use the action string in the `Intent` -- use `new Intent(this, TestActivity.class)` if the Java code is part of your application.