# Complete action using question is repeatedly asking in builf flavor apps created using modularisation in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-build-flavors, modularization

*Two build flavors, which are possible to install at a time in same phone. but showing this alert (Complete action using  ("App name")) always on each module wise selection on the app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> You will need to change the `<intent-filter>` for one of those two
> copies of the activity. Right now, both are advertising that they
> support the same action string. Change one to use a different action
> string.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084074/4370279